# What is startActivityForResult deprecated solution for bottomNavigationView item selected?

Tags: android, deprecated, bottomnavigationview, startactivityforresult

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Skbvc.jpg)  I want to pick image from a selected item (in that case, it is R.id.status ) from bottom navigation view and show the image in a recyclerview named statusList. How can I do this if startActivityForResult deprecated ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.
[Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to declare `private ActivityResultLauncher<String> imagePickerLauncher;`

After that here's how you launch the image picker

```
     // Launch the image picker
        imagePickerLauncher.launch("image/*");
```

And to retrieve the result you copy this code

```
        // Initialize the imagePickerLauncher
        imagePickerLauncher = registerForActivityResult(new 
        ActivityResultContracts.GetContent(), uri -> {
            if (uri != null) {
                 // Do something with the selected image URI
                 // For example, add it to the RecyclerView adapter
                
             }
         });
```